# 500 on javascript, wget. But works from browser

Tags: javascript, django, wget

I have a Django server running on localhost. When I type a get request on the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/article/asdasd
```

I get the proper page displayed. But when I try it in wget or from javascript I get a 500 Internal Server Error. At one point I saw Connection refused.

Any hints regarding where I should start looking to fix this is much appreciated.

More info if it helps:

When I use wget http://localhost:9000/... I get the following Connection refused error.

```
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1, fe80::1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:9000... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:9000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
2011-12-04 00:02:37 ERROR 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
```

But when using just wget http://127.0.0.1/... I just get the internal server error alone.

Comment: What is the code related to that particular request?

Comment: The error you show tries to connect to port 9000, but you show that you are trying to connect to port 1001. There must be more that you are not showing us.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, it was my mistake, I pasted the wrong message/command pair. It is 9000 everywhere.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I am not able to isolate the code, this is an already existing webapp - not my code. So I thought if we can crack why wget gets 500, then the javascript case should smooth out as well(if I am lucky)

Comment: Is there anything in the logs from Django?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Just prints that GET <URL> 500. But from the browser, it prints an identical URL and prints 200 and serves the page. Any tricks to get Django to spit out more information in the logs?

Comment: One more piece of information: This app has a frontend running on port 8000 and backend on port 9000. When I say it works on browser - I mean talking directly to 9000 using a well formed API url. What doesnt work is talking to 8000 (which is the frontend server) and then 8000 forwarding that request to 9000 which is when the Django either denies access or throws a 500 for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is there multiple request in your develop server? I find that the server in django would only available for only one request. Others would cause internal problem of the server.

Comment: If I do the request over and over again in the browser it works. So its just the javascript and wget that gives 500 on first time or on any number of times.